# Play a specific notification sound

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've created a dialog for selecting a notification sound for an app. I'm querying the notification sounds by getting a cursor from the RingtoneManager:

```
RingtoneManager manager = new RingtoneManager(this);
manager.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Cursor cursor = manager.getCursor();
```

I then store the full path to it by concatenating the sound path with the name.

This works fine when I set the selected sound as the notification sound but I can't get media player to play it on selection:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(path));
```

This throws an IllegalStateException:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown URL: content://media/internal/audio/media/Capella
```

Any ideas on how to get the correct path to a specific notification sound?

Comment: what value does path variable contain ?

Comment: @Darkie "content://media/internal/audio/media/Capella"

Comment: What I think is that after media/ you should be getting an id of the track not a name because when you access the path it gives you the path of the track with the id not with the name. you should check it ...

Comment: How do you get the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to play a sound is to use it's ID and not the name:

```
cursor.getInt(RingtoneManager.ID_COLUMN_INDEX)
```

Thanks Darkie for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

//in order to play the ringtone, you need to create a new Ringtone with RingtoneManager and pass it to a variable

Ringtone rt = mRingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri);
rt.play();

Thanks