# App-specific Notification Sound, Badge and Toast (WNS)

Tags: azure, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services, wns

Want I remember to have heard was that with WNS, you can specify a special sound for the notification you send, as is done for [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895719/play-a-specific-notification-sound).

I have looked on different sites [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761494.aspx), [urban](http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/wns_payload_reference.html) and [microsoft examples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/app-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148/), only reference I have found regarding [toast sounds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761492.aspx) does not seem to specify it.

Am I missing something ? Is it not possible for WNS?

Further is it possible to send a badge message together with toast and sound? Or what are the limits, cannot seem to find it in the above links.

I would like a link or a XML example I can try on my server. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to specify a custom toast notification sound via `WNS` you need to create the payload with the `audio` tag for example:

```
<toast launch=\"$param\">
   <audio src=\"ms-appx:///Assets/Sounds/sound.wav\"/>
   <visual>
       <binding template=\"ToastText04\">
           <text id=\"1\">$title</text>
           <text id=\"2\">$msg</text>
       </binding>
   </visual>
</toast>
```

Note the path to the audio file. For the sound to play, you need to have the audio file (which can be `mp3` too i think) prepackaged with your app. In this case the audio file is in the `Assets/Sounds` folder in your project. If the specified path does not exist, the default notification sound will play.

For the badge notifications, sound is not supported. You must send a seperate notification with the [badge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212851.aspx) schema.

Comment: Okay so just to clarify badge is a separate type you cannot integrate it? So I would need to send two notifications, e.g. Toast and sound, and one for tile and badge ? :)

Comment: Exactly! You can see the difference between [toast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230849.aspx) and [tile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212859.aspx) schemes on the links. The `toast` supports `audio`, and `tile` doesn't. For badge you need to send a seperate notification.

Comment: Great just one last follow up. Ms-apx, as you refer to in the sound is this for WinRT apps? Because mine is a Silverlight using wns. Should I need another prefix for sound? Lastly (I hope :) ) can you specify duration for the sound ?

Comment: For the silverlight part I'm not sure, but you can try. If it does not work try with `ms-appdata` or without the prefix (just src="/Assets..."). You can't specify duration, but you can create the audio file of your preferred duration.

Comment: I am sorry but hope a follow up is in order :) I remember to have read that when you send a WNS toast message you can specify the image shown with the notification is this correct? And if so what is the xml for it? Hope you have time to answer !

Comment: You can display images in toast notifications only on the `Windows 10` platform (when you create a Windows Universal App). For Windows 8.1 it is not possible. If you some day start to develop a Win10 app [check here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/07/02/adaptive-and-interactive-toast-notifications-for-windows-10.aspx) how the xml looks like

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. When you receive a notification on Wp8.1, there is an image/loge displayed with the text. How to decide what logo is displayed here with the xml? or is this not possible?

Comment: Aha, this is one of the images specified in your app manifest from the Visual Assets tap. I don't know which one it is but it is either the `Square 44x44` or the `Store Icon` images. This cannot be changed with the toast notification XML on WP8.1.